# Combine multiple variables into a single string and add comma

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have multiple strings:

```
address_1 = '226'
address_2 = 'Virginia Ave'
address_city = 'Trenton'
address_state = 'NJ'
address_country = 'US'
address_postal_code = '08610'
```

I am trying to combine them into a single string, separated from one another with comma, as follows:

```
"226 Virginia Ave, Trenton, NJ, 08610, US"
```

How can I combine my variables in a string, separate them using a comma, and in case any of the variable is missing, then do not display the extra comma?

I did this:

```
(address_1.to_s + ' ' + address_2.to_s + ' ' + address_city.to_s + ' ' + address_state.to_s + ' ' + address_postal_code.to_s + ' '  + address_country.to_s).squish
```

This gives output like this:

```
"226 Virginia Ave Trenton NJ 08610 US"
```

This happens because I am adding space `+ ' ' +`. If I do `+ ', ' +`, in case any of the `address_` is `nil` or empty, it still displays the extra `,`, and the address ends up looking like this:

```
"226 Virginia Ave, , , 08610, US"
```

Comment: Put them in an array and use `ary.compact.join(', ')`. Compact removes the missing items, join glues the rest together with the specified delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
address_1 = '226'
address_2 = 'Virginia Ave'
address_city = 'Trenton'
address_state = 'NJ'
address_country = 'US'
address_postal_code = '08610'

["#{address_1} #{address_2}", address_city, address_state, address_country, address_postal_code].map{|line| line.to_s.strip}.select{|line| !line.empty?}.join(', ')
```

This puts all the address elements in an array, maps to change all lines to a stripped string, and then selects lines that are not empty, and then joins using a comma and space.

The first element is address_1 and address 2 combined so as to avoid a comma after house number.

Comment: Many thanks, this works if any of the `address_` is `nil` but not in case if it is empty, in case of empty i still see extra commas

Comment: Ok, attached is a revised solution, converts all elements to strings but then strips out all empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using array compact. This may solve your problem.

```
address_arr = [address_1, address_2, address_city, address_state, address_country, address_postal_code]
no_empty_address = address_arr.reject{ |c| c.empty? }
no_empty_address.compact.join(', ')
```

Comment: this works if any of the `address_` is `nil` but not in case if it is empty, in case of empty i still see extra commas